# Remove specific <option> tag from <select> array that has a specific value from a WordPress Woo commerce site

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to remove a specific  tag from  array that has a specific value from a WordPress Woo commerce site. When I run the code in Stackoverflows code snippet the jquery executes and works as expected, but on the site it does not execute. What's even more confusing it that if I paste the jquery into the browser > inspector > console it also executes and deletes the desired  tag with the desired value.

CMS: WORDPRESS - Theme: DIVI | page builder: Elementor
CRM: Woo Commerce

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("1850-aprilaire-test-progressive") >= 0) {
        $('#dehumidifier-hanger-size option[value="Large (Fits 1870 model)"]').remove();
        alert('AWESOME jquery is WORKING');
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dehumidifier-hanger-size" class="" name="wccp_attribute_dehumidifier-hanger-size[1597339203]" data-attribute_name="attribute_dehumidifier-hanger-size" data-show_option_none="yes">
  <option value="">Choose an option</option>
  <option value="Regular (Fits 1820,1830,1850 models)" class="attached enabled">Regular (Fits 1820,1830,1850 models)</option>
  <option value="Large (Fits 1870 model)" class="attached enabled">Large (Fits 1870 model)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you see any errors in Console? What version of Jquery is WP loading? Why use `Query(document)`? Is the namespace not set to `jQuery()`?

Comment: @Twisty There are errors, but not anything specific to the attached jquery. Inspected page and <script> block is in the <head> tag, but not executing. Using jquery: 1.11.4. downloaded jquery WP updater plugin and jquery version remained the same. If I shouldn't use jquery(document) then what should the namespce be?

Comment: @Twisty Code executes because I receive the alert on page load, but line 2 doesn't execute: $('#dehumidifier-hanger-size option[value="Large (Fits 1870 model)"]').remove();. So jquery(document) <- namespace is correct.

Comment: This would suggest that the Selector fails to select the element for some reason.

Comment: @Twisty That was my conclusion as well, but the code works when pasted into the Console. LOL. Not sure where the interference is coming from.

Comment: Is the `select` tag created dynamically with JS or via the template?

Comment: It might be created or added after the document is `ready`. So maybe trigger it to happen when the select element completes loading. Look at `.load()` callback.

Comment: Yes I believe the select tag is created dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I would try something a bit more loose. Maybe you're being too specific.

```
jQuery(function($) {
  if(window.location.href.indexOf("1850-aprilaire-test-progressive") >= 0) {
    var el = $("#dehumidifier-hanger-size option[value^='Large']");
    console.log("Found Element", el[0]);
    el.remove();
  } else {
    console.log("Not the correct page.");
  }
});
```

If you see `undefined` in console, then you missed the selection. If you see `<option...` you hit the right thing.

Comment: Same result when I paste it into the console the code executes, but when I paste into DIVI > theme options > integrations the code does not execute, but the script shows up in the head of the page.

Comment: BTW I'm running an if conditional statement depending on the page URL index. I've edited my original code snippet to include everything.

Comment: @HobartHobieMunsell if you see nothing in Console, this means your IF statement was FALSE and did not run the code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this? Using a `load` event handler in most of the cases solves the problem because probably this field is created after the `ready` event, hence you see the selector working through the console but not inside your `ready` handler.

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {

  $( document ).on( 'load', function() {
    $('#dehumidifier-hanger-size option[value="Large (Fits 1870 model)"]').remove();
    alert('AWESOME jquery is WORKING');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dehumidifier-hanger-size" class="" name="wccp_attribute_dehumidifier-hanger-size[1597339203]" data-attribute_name="attribute_dehumidifier-hanger-size" data-show_option_none="yes">
  <option value="">Choose an option</option>
  <option value="Regular (Fits 1820,1830,1850 models)" class="attached enabled">Regular (Fits 1820,1830,1850 models)</option>
  <option value="Large (Fits 1870 model)" class="attached enabled">Large (Fits 1870 model)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nope $( document ).on( 'load', function() { <---- Does not work.

Comment: @HobartHobieMunsell Do you have a child theme installed or are you saving your code inside the customizer?

Comment: it's a child theme using DIVI > theme options> integrations. In the WP admin Dashboard

Comment: Got it to work on Chrome/IE/FF/OPR just not Safari.

Comment: Create and enqueue a new JS in your child theme. It should be working that way.

Answer (score 0):

@twisted @vmank Using a $('#id').on('load', function - to delete desired option. executes in console, but can't find desired object. returns as undefined. Obviously the entire line 2 is in the wrong place even though the code syntax in correct. can either of you help?

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#dehumidifier-hanger-size').on('load', function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("1850-aprilaire-test-progressive") >= 0) {
      var el = $("#dehumidifier-hanger-size option[value^='Large']");
      console.log("Found Element", el[0]);
      el.remove();
    } else {
      console.log("Not the correct page.");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dehumidifier-hanger-size" class="" name="wccp_attribute_dehumidifier-hanger-size[1597339203]" data-attribute_name="attribute_dehumidifier-hanger-size" data-show_option_none="yes">
  <option value="">Choose an option</option>
  <option value="Regular (Fits 1820,1830,1850 models)" class="attached enabled">Regular (Fits 1820,1830,1850 models)</option>
  <option value="Large (Fits 1870 model)" class="attached enabled">Large (Fits 1870 model)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If you see nothing in console then this code is not running. You will need to determine why this code does not appear in your Source or why it's not bubbling up over some other code.

Answer (score 0):

@twisted @vmank So, GOOD NEWS!!! Got the jquery to work on Chrome/FF/IE/OPR!!!! BAD NEWS: Doesn't work on Safari. Can either of you point me in the right direction?

BTW, thanks for all your help. REALLY appreciate it!!!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("1850-aprilaire-test") >= 0) {
        $( document ).on( 'click', '#dehumidifier-hanger-size', function()  {
                var el = $('#dehumidifier-hanger-size option[value^="Large"]');
                el.attr('disabled','disabled');
                console.log("Found Element", el[0]);
        });
        } else {
        console.log("Not the correct page.");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dehumidifier-hanger-size" class="" name="wccp_attribute_dehumidifier-hanger-size[1597339203]" data-attribute_name="attribute_dehumidifier-hanger-size" data-show_option_none="yes">
  <option value="">Choose an option</option>
  <option value="Regular (Fits 1820,1830,1850 models)" class="attached enabled">Regular (Fits 1820,1830,1850 models)</option>
  <option value="Large (Fits 1870 model)" class="attached enabled" disabled="disabled">Large (Fits 1870 model)</option>
</select>
```